# How to display the excel cell value as "1/1/1901" in formula bar and display the same as "1901-01-01" in the corresponding cell using perl

Tags: excel, perl

We have a requirement to generate the excel file and the cell value should be shown as mm/dd/yyyy format (1/1/1901) in Formula bar and display the same as yyyy-mm-dd format (1901-01-01) in the corresponding cell. Can some one please help how this can be achieved using Perl, Please refer the below screen shot which will show how we need.

We are using the module Excel::Writer::XLSX and we have tried the below code, but it is showing the same format in both formula bar and cell.

```
        if ($cell =~ qr[^(\d{4})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})$])
        {
        my $format1 = $workbook->add_format(num_format => 'yyyy-mm-dd');
        my $date = sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d", $2, $3, $1;
        $worksheet->write_date_time( $iR, $iC, ${date}, $format1);
        }
```

Screen shot

Comment: Did you look at the formatting that your example file has? It looks like you're doing the right thing, but maybe you can learn something from the original file. Also might help to use Spreadsheet::XLSX to take a look at what that thinks the format is like in your file.

Comment: why do you removed the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> The most direct way is to convert your dates to the ISO8601
>   **yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss** date format and use the write_date_time()
>   worksheet method:

The demo:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $wb = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );
my $ws = $wb->add_worksheet();

$ws->set_column('A:B', 25);

my $date_format = $wb->add_format(num_format => 'yyyy-mm-dd');

my($d,$m,$y) = (20,1,1901);

#your current
my $current = sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d", $d,$m,$y;
$ws->write('A1', 'using: %02d/%02d/%04d');
$ws->write_date_time( 'B1', $current, $date_format );

#you want
my $wanted = sprintf "%04d-%02d-%02dT", $y,$m,$d;
$ws->write('A2', 'using: %04d-%02d-%02dT');
$ws->write_date_time( 'B2', $wanted, $date_format );
```

produces in excel

[image: excel screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked as per our requirement.